# How to access model from within a view in emberjs using javascript?

Tags: javascript, ember.js

How do I access the model defined in index route model hook from within the container init function I want the container to iterate on the model and create child view for each object in the model array?
Here is the code sample:

```
App= Ember.Application.create();
    App.Router.map(function(){

})

App.IndexRoute=Ember.Route.extend({
    model: function(){
        return arr;
    }
})
App.MainView = Em.View.extend({
    classNames: ['mainView']
});

App.MyContainerView = Em.ContainerView.extend({
    tagName:"tbody",
});
var container = App.MyContainerView.create({
    init: function() {
        //this._super();
        //this.pushObject(App.FirstView.create());
        //this.pushObject(App.SecondView.create());
    }
});

App.SingleTaskView = Em.View.extend({
    templateName:'single-task',
    tagName:""
});


App.IndexController= Ember.ArrayController.extend({
    actions: {
        newTask: function(){
            var containerView = Em.View.views['my_container_view']
          var childView = containerView.createChildView(App.SingleTaskView);
            containerView.get('childViews').pushObject(childView);
        }
    }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

You are using deprecated items (ArrayController, ContainerView) cf [release note](https://www.emberjs.com/deprecations/v1.x/)

Which version of Ember are you using ?

Comment: version 1.0.0 of emberjs can you point me to cdn link of a newer version?

Comment: sure : [user guide](https://guides.emberjs.com/v2.14.0/) - [last release 2.14](https://emberjs.com/builds/release) on this link you have direct links - [changelog](https://github.com/emberjs/data/blob/v2.14.3/CHANGELOG.md)

Comment: thanks now since i am not using the ember cli can you list me the dependencies of emberjs, i use jquery, handlebars,and ember-data, but i get this errors:Uncaught ReferenceError: define is not defined
    at handlebars.amd.min.js:27,  Cannot read property 'initialize' of undefined
    at ember.min.js:865

Comment: I never did that, but I think you need to import ember, ember-data and ember-template-compiler

Comment: getting this error: ember-data.min.js:1 Uncaught Error: Could not find module `ember-data/index` imported from `ember-data/initializers/ember-data

Comment: Ember at this point expects you to be using the CLI tool, is there a reason you can't use it? You'll hit far fewer errors if you do ...